# In Bigquery: How to pick max(date) row while performing full outer join in case of duplicates?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, outer-join

I'm performing `full outer join` to combine two tables in bigquery in order to get all rows and columns from both the tables.

```
select distinct t1.Org,t1.begindate,t1.enddate,<fetch unit based on enddate> as f_Unit
from table1 t1
full outer join table2 t2
on t1.Org = t2.Org
```

Now the problem here is, both the tables have some rows with same value for all columns except `enddate` and `Unit` column

**table1**

```
Org     Store   Product     begindate   enddate     FalUnit
01      12      xx          2020-04-16  9999-12-31  5
01      13      yy          2011-03-23  null        0
```

**table2**

```
Org     Store   Product     begindate   enddate     Unit
01      12      xx          null        null        1
01      14      zz          null        null        3
```

- in that case have to pick up the `max(enddate)` and it's respective `Unit` as well.

**Output_Table**

```
Org     Store   Product     begindate   enddate     FalUnit     Unit    f_Unit
01      12      xx          2020-04-16  9999-12-31  5           null    5
01      13      yy          2011-03-23  null        0           null    0
01      14      zz          null        null        null        3       3
```

How to include this condition to this query or any other approach possible other than joins ?
Any help will be appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.  Your query is a bit confusing.  If the columns are all the same, why does your query only pull some from the first table?

Comment: Have included samples and expected output as well.

Comment: . . I don't see it.  The `begin` date is not the same.

Comment: That's actually okie. BeginDate may vary, Have to consider max(EndDate) alone

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I am thinking a prioritization.  Something like this:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.org = t2.org and t1.store = t2.store and t1.product = t2.product
                 );
```

At the very least, this will return your specified results for the specified data in the question.

Comment: Nope.. This is still bringing up both the rows from both the tables instead of the row with max enddate alone.